# How to retrieve Mongodb child value without parents object/field name

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to query one type of child objects (child object/field with same name under different parents object/field ) directly without invoking the parents name in the find() command

For example I have

```
MondoDB
{
eatable.fruits.tomato
}

{
eatable.vegetables.tomato
}
```

Here each tomato is a parameter which have some value assigned in it, And I have tomato under two different objects/fields,

Is there a way to query and retrieve  all values of tomato without using the field/object names "fruits" or "vegetables" in the find () command.

Answer (score 0):

**As of now, there is no direct way to search for child fields without knowing the parent fields** but we do have the workaround. The idea is to first filter the documents by adding the constraints in `find()` method and then iterate over the response and print out the values of 'tomato' key where ever its present as leaf element.

Following is the example:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(
    function processDoc(document){
        let keys = Object.keys(document);
        keys.forEach(
            function(key){  
                let value = document[key];
                if(typeof value === typeof Object()){
                    processDoc(value);  // Its an embedded document, thus process it again
                }else if(key == 'tomato'){ 
                    print(value);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d63ac599d32d1c15cf5ea5e"),
    "eatable" : {
        "vegetables" : {
            "tomato" : "veg1"
        },
        "fruits" : {
            "tomato" : "fru1",
            "banana": "fru1"
        },
        "misc" : {
            "item" : {
                "tomato" : "misc1"
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d63ac599d32d1c15cf5ea5f"),
    "eatable" : {
        "fruits" : {
            "tomato" : "fru2"
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
veg1
fru1
misc1
fru2
```